# Footnotes numbers appear at the end of footnote

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word

My footnotes are appearing with the text first and at the end the footnote number. I have made some changes recently to my paragraph settings, but I don't know why the footnotes are coming out upside down?

Answer (score 0):

The Footnote alignment is depends on the Margin settings of your document. Could you please check your margin changes that you have done recently and try changing various margin levels to fix this issue.

Hope this helps.